# Zend Framework 2: Navigation

Tags: php, zend-framework2

In my controller I create the Navigation object and passing it to the view

```
$navigation = new \Zend\Navigation\Navigation(array(
    array(
            'label' => 'Album',
            'controller' => 'album',
            'action' => 'index',
            'route' => 'album',
        ),
    ));
```

There trying to use it

```
<?php echo $this->navigation($this->navigation)->menu() ?>
```

And get the error:

> Fatal error: Zend\Navigation\Exception\DomainException: Zend\Navigation\Page\Mvc::getHref cannot execute as no Zend\Mvc\Router\RouteStackInterface instance is composed in Zend\View\Helper\Navigation\AbstractHelper.php on line 471

But navigation which I use in layout, so as it is written here: http://adam.lundrigan.ca/2012/07/quick-and-dirty-zf2-zend-navigation/ works. What is my mistake?

Thank you.

Answer (score 10):

The problem is a missing Router (or to be more precise, a `Zend\Mvc\Router\RouteStackInterface`). A route stack is a collection of routes and can use a route name to turn that into an url. Basically it accepts a route name and creates an url for you:

```
$url = $routeStack->assemble('my/route');
```

This happens inside the MVC Pages of `Zend\Navigation` too. The page has a `route` parameter and when there is a router available, the page assembles it's own url (or in `Zend\Navigation` terms, an `href`). If you do not provide the router, it cannot assemble the route and thus throws an exception.

You must inject the router in every page of the navigation:

```
$navigation = new Navigation($config);
$router     = $serviceLocator->get('router');

function injectRouter($navigation, $router) {
  foreach ($navigation->getPages() as $page) {
    if ($page instanceof MvcPage) {
      $page->setRouter($router);
    }

    if ($page->hasPages()) {
      injectRouter($page, $router);
    }
  }
}
```

As you see it is a recursive function, injecting the router into every page. Tedious! Therefore there is a factory to do this for you. There are **four simple steps** to make this happen.

**STEP ONE**

Put the navigation configuration in your module configuration first. Just as you have a `default` navigation, you can create a second one `secondary`.

```
'navigation' => array(
    'secondary' => array(
        'page-1' => array(
            'label' => 'First page',
            'route' => 'route-1'
        ),
        'page-2' => array(
            'label' => 'Second page',
            'route' => 'route-2'
        ),
    ),
),
```

You have routes to your first page (`route-1`) and second page (`route-2`).

**STEP TWO**

A factory will convert this into a navigation object structure, you need to create a class for that first. Create a file `SecondaryNavigationFactory.php` in your MyModule/Navigation/Service directory.

```
namespace MyModule\Navigation\Service;

use Zend\Navigation\Service\DefaultNavigationFactory;

class SecondaryNavigationFactory extends DefaultNavigationFactory
{
    protected function getName()
    {
        return 'secondary';
    }
}
```

See I put the name `secondary` here, which is the same as your navigation key.

**STEP THREE**

You must register this factory to the service manager. Then the factory can do it's work and turn the configuration file into a `Zend\Navigation` object. You can do this in your module.config.php:

```
'service_manager' => array(
    'factories' => array(
        'secondary_navigation' => 'MyModule\Navigation\Service\SecondaryNavigationFactory'
    ),
)
```

See I made a service `secondary_navigation` here, where the factory will return a `Zend\Navigation` instance then. If you do now `$sm->get('secondary_navigation')` you will see that is a `Zend\Navigation\Navigation` object.

**STEP FOUR**

Tell the view helper to use this navigation and not the default one. The navigation view helper accepts a "navigation" parameter where you can state which navigation you want. In this case, the service manager has a service `secondary_navigation` and that is the one we need.

```
<?= $this->navigation('secondary_navigation')->menu() ?>
```

Now you will have the navigation `secondary` used in this view helper.

*Disclosure: this answer is the same as I gave on this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12973806/434223*

Comment: This is a great example. It works until I want to use a view partial for rendering. I'm using this for my main navigation, but that shouldn't matter. Here's what I'm using: 

echo $this->navigation('navigation')->menu()->setPartial(array('navigation.phtml', 'Application'));

Fatal error: Zend\ServiceManager\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException: Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager::get was unable to fetch or create an instance for menu in /myapp/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/View/Helper/Navigation/AbstractHelper.php on line 471

Answer (score 2):

btw. you don't need to define `controller` and `action` if you define a `route`, only if your route is generic and controller/action are variable segments.

Comment: You are right, thanks for the comments. But if so fix the announcement page error remains. The only option when the code is running, when it looks so: `$navigation = new \Zend\Navigation\Navigation(array(
   array(
    'label' => 'Album',
    'uri'=>'/'
   ),
  ));` When the url is set directly.

Comment: hm dunno, but do you have this in your module.php? `$application = $e->getApplication(); $eventManager = $application->getEventManager(); $moduleRouteListener = new ModuleRouteListener(); $moduleRouteListener->attach($eventManager);`

Comment: Yes in Module.php in the method of onBootstrap I have exactly the same code. What is interesting is the url view helper in my view work correctly. Code `$this->url('album/default', array('controller'=>'album', 'action'=>'edit', 'id' => $id))` works very well and displays a link on the page. It is not clear that interferes with the proper display of the menu. If there are any thoughts, I will be glad to hear them. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is indeed that the routes can't be resolved without the router. I would expect the navigation class to solve that issue, but obviously you have to do it on your own. I just wrote a view helper to introduce the router with the MVC pages.

Here's how I use it within the view:

```
$navigation = $this->navigation();
$navigation->addPage(
    array(
        'route' => 'language',
        'label' => 'language.list.nav'
    )
);
$this->registerNavigationRouter($navigation);
echo $navigation->menu()->render();
```

The view helper:

```
<?php
namespace JarJar\View\Helper;

use Zend\View\Helper\AbstractHelper;
use Zend\View\Helper\Navigation;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorAwareInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface;
use Zend\Navigation\Page\Mvc;

class RegisterNavigationRouter extends AbstractHelper implements ServiceLocatorAwareInterface
{
    protected $serviceLocator;

    public function setServiceLocator(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator)
    {
        $this->serviceLocator = $serviceLocator;
    }

    public function getServiceLocator()
    {
        return $this->serviceLocator;
    }

    public function __invoke(Navigation $navigation)
    {
        $router = $this->getRouter();
        foreach ($navigation->getPages() as $page) {
            if ($page instanceof Mvc) {
                $page->setRouter($router);
            }
        }
    }

    protected function getRouter()
    {
        $router = $this->getServiceLocator()->getServiceLocator()->get('router');
        return $router;
    }
}
```

Don't forget to add the view helper in your config as invokable instance:

```
'view_helpers' => array(
    'invokables' => array(
        'registerNavigationRouter' => 'JarJar\View\Helper\RegisterNavigationRouter'
    )
),
```

It's not a great solution, but it works.