# How to set up 2 navigations in zf2?

Tags: navigation, config, zend-framework2

I have a config for main navigation [link](http://pastie.org/5083400) and the second just with 1 [link](http://pastie.org/5083402). The main navigation is working fine, but when I try setting up a *second* navigation bar in module like this:

```
$config = $e->getApplication()->getServiceManager()->get('config');
$navigation = new \Zend\Navigation\Navigation($config['navigation_footer']);
$e->getApplication()->getServiceManager()
    ->setService('new_navigation', $navigation);`
```

I get an error when I render it in the view:

> Fatal error: Zend\Navigation\Exception\DomainException: Zend\Navigation\Page\Mvc::getHref cannot execute as no Zend\Mvc\Router\RouteStackInterface instance is composed in /home/cawa/www/sp-app/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/View/Helper/Navigation/AbstractHelper.php on line 471

Comment: The error message is shown on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12781623/zend-framework-2-navigation but there is no accepted answer on that question-

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The problem is a missing Router (or to be more precise, a `Zend\Mvc\Router\RouteStackInterface`). A route stack is a collection of routes and can use a route name to turn that into an url. Basically it accepts a route name and creates an url for you:

```
$url = $routeStack->assemble('my/route');
```

This happens inside the MVC Pages of `Zend\Navigation` too. The page has a `route` parameter and when there is a router available, the page assembles it's own url (or in `Zend\Navigation` terms, an `href`). If you do not provide the router, it cannot assemble the route and thus throws an exception.

You must inject the router in every page of the navigation:

```
$navigation = new Navigation($config);
$router     = $serviceLocator->get('router');

function injectRouter($navigation, $router) {
  foreach ($navigation->getPages() as $page) {
    if ($page instanceof MvcPage) {
      $page->setRouter($router);
    }

    if ($page->hasPages()) {
      injectRouter($page, $router);
    }
  }
}
```

As you see it is a recursive function, injecting the router into every page. Tedious! Therefore there is a factory to do this for you. There are **four simple steps** to make this happen.

**STEP ONE**

Put the navigation configuration in your module configuration first. Just as you have a `default` navigation, you can create a second one `secondary`.

```
'navigation' => array(
    'secondary' => array(
        'page-1' => array(
            'label' => 'First page',
            'route' => 'route-1'
        ),
        'page-2' => array(
            'label' => 'Second page',
            'route' => 'route-2'
        ),
    ),
),
```

You have routes to your first page (`route-1`) and second page (`route-2`).

**STEP TWO**

A factory will convert this into a navigation object structure, you need to create a class for that first. Create a file `SecondaryNavigationFactory.php` in your MyModule/Navigation/Service directory.

```
namespace MyModule\Navigation\Service;

use Zend\Navigation\Service\DefaultNavigationFactory;

class SecondaryNavigationFactory extends DefaultNavigationFactory
{
    protected function getName()
    {
        return 'secondary';
    }
}
```

See I put the name `secondary` here, which is the same as your navigation key.

**STEP THREE**

You must register this factory to the service manager. Then the factory can do it's work and turn the configuration file into a `Zend\Navigation` object. You can do this in your module.config.php:

```
'service_manager' => array(
    'factories' => array(
        'secondary_navigation' => 'MyModule\Navigation\Service\SecondaryNavigationFactory'
    ),
)
```

See I made a service `secondary_navigation` here, where the factory will return a `Zend\Navigation` instance then. If you do now `$sm->get('secondary_navigation')` you will see that is a `Zend\Navigation\Navigation` object.

**STEP FOUR**

Tell the view helper to use this navigation and not the default one. The navigation view helper accepts a "navigation" parameter where you can state which navigation you want. In this case, the service manager has a service `secondary_navigation` and that is the one we need.

```
<?= $this->navigation('secondary_navigation')->menu() ?>
```

Now you will have the navigation `secondary` used in this view helper.

Comment: Works perfectly even with ACL

Comment: What did you mean by saying "You must inject the router in every page of the navigation" ? Where I need to write that code ?