# ZF2 - multiple nav menus using the navigation view helper

Tags: php, navigation, zend-framework2, view-helpers

I am trying to use a main navigation in combination with a submenu for more specific navigating.

In my *layout* I am calling the view helper like this:

```
$this->navigation('main_navigation')->menu()
```

and in my *view* I am calling it like this:

```
$this->navigation('sub_navigation')->menu()
```

The problem is that whenever I call the `navigation()` view helper a ***more than once***, it just outputs the *second one* in both places.  In other words, it's printing the **subnav** for *both* the main nav *and* the subnav menus.

My merged config looks like this:

```
'navigation' => array(
    'main' => array(
        'home' => array(
            'label' => 'Home',
            'route' => 'myroute',
        ),
        'somepage' => array(
            'label' => 'Me',
            'route' => 'somepage'
        )
    ),
    'sub' => array(
        'test' => array(
            'label'  => 'Test',
            'route'  => 'myroute',
            'action' => 'test'
        ),
        'other-test' => array(
            'label'  => 'Other Test',
            'route'  => 'myroute',
            'action' => 'other-test'
        )
    )
)
```

How do I use the `navigation` view helper so that it will print the correct menu for each call?

Comment: See answer of this Question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12972316/how-to-set-up-2-navigations-in-zf2

Comment: @Sam That doesn't work. I spent 6 hours last night in the ZFtalk IRC channel talking to one of the _creators_ of ZfcAdmin and ZfcUser and he was able to successfully duplicate my _error_ without being able to _resolve_ it. I _already_ have exactly that for my app and it **doesn't work.**  That is the point here.

Comment: @Sam thank you for finding that anyway. :)

Comment: You're welcome, it appeared to me like the same methology, but if it isn't im FAR behind most in #zftalk :D Got no other advice but that ^^

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `menu`, `breadcrumbs`, `sitemap` and `links` helpers are registered as plugins. If you call `$this->navigation('main_navigation')` for the first time, the `Zend\View\Helper\Navigation` creates the container "main_navigation". If you then call `menu()` **for the first time** the `Zend\View\Helper\Navigation\Menu` object is created **and directly** the container is injected.

This indicates the flaw: if you call `$this->navigation('sub_navigation')` now, the navigation container is loaded in the `navigation()` view helper. When you then call `menu()`, the menu view helper is already created. So the new container is not injected anymore.

Clearly this is a bug in the code base. There is one quick fix: the menu helper can also accept the container string:

```
<?php echo $this->navigation()->menu('main_navigation'); ?>
<?php echo $this->navigation()->menu('sub_navigation'); ?>
```

I have filed an issue about it and the bug will be fixed.

Comment: No problem! The issue about this can be found here: https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/issues/2817