# Separate navigation config for zend framework modules

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I have the following configuration for my navigation in my application module in `Application/config/module.config.php`:

```
    'navigation' => array(
        'default' => array(
            array(
                'label' => 'Home',
                'route' => 'home'
            )            
        )
    )
```

I have the following configuration for my navigation in my cortana module in `Cortana/config/module.config.php`:

```
    'navigation' => array(
        'default' => array(
            array(
                'label' => 'Home',
                'route' => 'cortana-home'
            ),
            array(
                'label' => 'Resources',
                'route' => 'cortana-resources'
            ),
            array(
                'label' => 'Reports',
                'route' => 'cortana-reports'
            ),
            array(
                'label' => 'Services',
                'route' => 'cortana-services'
            ),
            array(
                'label' => 'System',
                'route' => 'cortana-system'
            )
        )
    )
```

Im using the layout in my `Cortana` modulle. Here is the navigation code:

```
           <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                    <?php echo $this->navigation('navigation')
                                    ->menu()
                                    ->setMinDepth(0)
                                    ->setMaxDepth(0)
                                    ->setUlClass('nav navbar-nav');
                    ?>
                </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
```

And finally, unfortunately my result compiles the following HTML:

```
                <li>
        <a href="&#x2F;cortana&#x2F;public&#x2F;">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="active">
        <a href="&#x2F;cortana&#x2F;public&#x2F;cortana">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="&#x2F;cortana&#x2F;public&#x2F;cortana&#x2F;resources">Resources</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="&#x2F;cortana&#x2F;public&#x2F;cortana&#x2F;reports">Reports</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="&#x2F;cortana&#x2F;public&#x2F;cortana&#x2F;services">Services</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="&#x2F;cortana&#x2F;public&#x2F;cortana&#x2F;system">System</a>
    </li>
</ul>                </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
```

As you can see, there is 2 home navigation pages. **It looks like the code merged the `Application` navigation module and the `Cortana` navigation module.**

What I need is to have a navigation for the `Cortana` module and then a separate navigation for the `Application` module.

**UPDATE**

I've also tried changing the `navigation` key to `cortana-navigation` the following:

`/Cortana/config/module.config.php`

```
'service_manager' => array(       
    'factories' => array(
        'cortana-navigation' => 'Zend\Navigation\Service\DefaultNavigationFactory'
    )
),

    'cortana-navigation' => array(
        'default' => array(
            array(
                'label' => 'Home',
                'route' => 'cortana-home'
            ),
            array(
                'label' => 'Resources',
                'route' => 'cortana-resources'
            ),
            array(
                'label' => 'Reports',
                'route' => 'cortana-reports'
            ),
            array(
                'label' => 'Services',
                'route' => 'cortana-services'
            ),
            array(
                'label' => 'System',
                'route' => 'cortana-system'
            )
        )
    )
```

And then in my `Cortana layout` (`Cortana/view/layout/layout.phtml`)

```
 <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                        <?php echo $this->navigation('cortana-navigation')
                                        ->menu()
                                        ->setMinDepth(0)
                                        ->setMaxDepth(0)
                                        ->setUlClass('nav navbar-nav');
                        ?>
                    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
```

And  now my result compiled HTML is:

```
 <ul class="nav&#x20;navbar-nav">
            <li>
            <a href="&#x2F;cortana&#x2F;public&#x2F;">Home</a>
            </li>
            </ul>                </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
```

I unfortunately have no explanation for why its now using the `Application` navigation (`navigation`) instead of the (`cortana-navigation`) but it does mean that its responding to the change of `factory`

**SECOND UPDATE**

I did notice that in the file `Zend/Navigaiton/Service/DefaultNavigationFactory.php' :

```
    class DefaultNavigationFactory extends AbstractNavigationFactory
    {
        /**
         * @return string
         */
        protected function getName()
        {
            return 'default';
        }
    }
```

This might mean something with using the default name

Comment: From memory in ZF2 your array index `navigation` is for want of a better term is the 'name' of that navigation.  Therefore you could easily define one as `cortana-navigation` and one as just `navigation`.

Comment: @JackSkinner See updates

Comment: @JackSkinner see second updates

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/12996800/131824

Comment: See following URL: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12972316/how-to-set-up-2-navigations-in-zf2/12973806#12973806