# ZF2 different menus in different controllers

Tags: php, zend-framework, menu, navigation, zend-framework2

I have a question about menus in ZF2.

I have one module, and two controllers, for example. In a layout I can render menus:

```
<?php echo $this->navigation()->menu('mainMenu'); ?>
<?php echo $this->navigation()->menu('settingsMenu'); ?>
```

But I want to render them separately depending on current controller and in a layout it must be something like this:

```
$this->menu;
```

How can I register variable "menu" as a menu depending on controller.
I tried to do it in "onBootstrap" method but i've failed.

---

I did it this way:

Module.php:

```
public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e)
{
    $e->getApplication()->getEventManager()->attach(MvcEvent::EVENT_DISPATCH, array($this, 'headMenuAttach'));
}

public function headMenuAttach(MvcEvent $e)
{
    $controller = $e->getTarget();

    if (method_exists($controller, 'getHeadMenu')) {
        $menu = $controller->getHeadMenu();
        $controller->layout()->setVariable('MainMenu', $menu);
    }
}
```

layout:

```
$this->navigation()->menu($this->MainMenu);
```

controller:

```
public function getHeadMenu()
{
    return 'settingsMenu';
}
```

Is it correct in a ZF2-way? :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a second navigation object by extending the DefaultNavigationFactory, as Jurian explains [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12972316/how-to-set-up-2-navigations-in-zf2).

Comment: I already have two objects: 'mainMenu' and 'settingsMenu' registered in ServiceManager. But I can't understand how can I register "menu" in a View to contain the desired me the menu depending on the controller.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Shared Event Manager to target the event for specific namespaces, therefor target your modules separately.

```
/**
 * On bootstrap event
 * 
 * @param \Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent $e
 */
public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e)
{
    // .. other stuff here //

    /**
     * Only in our application namespace
     * Put this part inside Application Modules Module.php
     */
    $e->getApplication()->getEventManager()->getSharedManager()
        ->attach('Application', 'dispatch', function($e) {
        $controller = $e->getTarget();
        $controllerClass = get_class($controller);
        $moduleNamespace = substr($controllerClass, 0, strpos($controllerClass, '\\'));

        // Attach Nav 1 here
        if (method_exists($controller, 'getHeadMenu')) {
            $menu = $controller->getHeadMenu();
            $controller->layout()->setVariable('MainMenu', $menu);
        }

    }, 100);

    /**
     * Only in our MyModule namespace
     * Put this part inside MyModule Modules Module.php
     */
    $e->getApplication()->getEventManager()->getSharedManager()
        ->attach('MyModule', 'dispatch', function($e) {

        // Attach Nav 2 here

    }, 100);
}
```

You would want to put each entry in it's own Modules Module.php bootstrap method, but you get the idea.

You only target the Dispatch events in your modules namespace, rather than attaching to all dispatch events system wide.