# How do I get navigation configs into my view helper?

Tags: php, zend-framework2

Using zf2 I have a view helper that looks like this:

```
class Navbar extends AbstractHelper implements ServiceLocatorAwareInterface {

    public function setServiceLocator(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator) {
        $this->serviceLocator = $serviceLocator;
        return $this;  
    }

    public function getServiceLocator() {
        return $this->serviceLocator;
    }

    public function __invoke($container) {
        $partial = array('partial/subNav.phtml','thisMeansNothing');
        //github.com/zendframework/zf2/issues/3457
        $navigation = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('navigation');
        $navigation($container)->menu()->setPartial($partial);

        return $navigation->menu()->render();

    }
}
```

This works really well for me because I can just do `echo $this->navbar('navigation');` in my views.

In my module's module.config.php I have this:

```
...
    'navigation' => array(
        'default' => array(
            array(
                'label' => 'eeee',
                'route' => 'link',
            ),
            array(
                'label' => 'sdlfkj',
                'route' => 'link',
            ),
            array(
                'label' => 'sdlkfj',
                'route' => 'link',
            ),
        ),

        'test' => array(
            array(
                'label' => 'aaaa',
                'route' => 'link',
            ),
            array(
                'label' => 'bbbbb',
                'route' => 'link',
            ),
        ),
    ), 
...
```

How do I pull the 'test' config under navigation into my view helper instead of the default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are loading another navigation 'tree'. This tree must be setup independently and unfortunately, that does take a couple of steps. I have earlier explained how to fix this [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12972316/how-to-set-up-2-navigations-in-zf2/12973806#12973806).

Basically, you have to create a second navigation factory, link the factory to a navigation service name and use that service name in your view helpers.

Comment: jeeze that kinda stinks. So after I do all of that I should just be able to call it in my views like: echo $this->navbar('secondary_navigation_tree'); right? Also, side note, do you find zf2 developers implementing custom navigation like this or do most just use community modules like spiffy?

Comment: Yes, if you create the factory and link it in your module config, it works like that. We never use spiffy navigation because there are other issues with. We don't have many navigations (1 - 3) so that's easy to write a single time for a complete project.

Comment: hmm I can't make this work in my code. I set everything up and tried changing the code in the view to echo $this->navbar('test') then tried changing the code in the helper to  $this->getServiceLocator()->get('test') but neither worked and I get: "Zend\View\HelperPluginManager::get was unable to fetch or create an instance for test"

Comment: Can you test the code in my answer (so without your navbar() helper) first? If that fails, you know there's an error in the initial setup. If that's OK, you know there's  an error in your navbar helper.

Comment: Whoops I'm super sorry it was a damn typo, works perfectly, thanks for the help. Specifically the problem was in my view: echo $this->navbar('wrong_factory_name')