# The navigation view helper in one of my modules is breaking the navbar in the Application modules layout.phtml

Tags: php, templates, zend-framework2

Using zf2 with the default skeleton app I have a view helper located in a module that I use to render a subnav bar for the module. It looks like this:

```
class Navbar extends AbstractHelper implements ServiceLocatorAwareInterface {

    public function setServiceLocator(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator) {
        $this->serviceLocator = $serviceLocator;
        return $this;  
    }

    public function getServiceLocator() {
        return $this->serviceLocator;
    }

    public function __invoke($container) {
        $partial = array('partial/subNav.phtml','thisMeansNothing');
        //github.com/zendframework/zf2/issues/3457
        $navigation = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('navigation');
        $navigation($container)->menu()->setPartial($partial);

        return $navigation->menu()->render();

    }
}
```

In the module's module.config.php I have this:

```
...
    'navigation' => array(
        'subnav' => array(
            array(
                'label' => 'aaa',
                'route' => 'link',
            ),
            array(
                'label' => 'bbb',
                'route' => 'link',
            ),
            array(
                'label' => 'ccc',
                'route' => 'link',
            ),
        ),

...
```

Following [these steps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12972316/how-to-set-up-2-navigations-in-zf2/12973806#12973806) I extended DefaultNavigationFactory to load the "subnav" config for this module and registered it in module.config.php:

```
'service_manager' => array(
    'factories' => array(
        'subnav_navigation' => 
            'myModule\Navigation\Service\SubNavNavigationFactory'
```

This works really well for me because I can just do `echo $this->navbar('subnav_navigation');` in my views in the module.

This worked fine, but now I want to modify my site wide navbar in my Application module. I don't need a view helper for this as I can just create it in layout\layout.phtml were it is by default.

I modified the module.config.php for the Application module like this:

```
'navigation' => array(
    'default' => array(
        array(
            'label' => 'wwww',
            'route' => 'wwww',
        ),
        array(
            'label' => 'qqq',
            'route' => 'qqq',
            'pages' => array(
                array(
                    'label' => 'sdf',
                    'route' => 'sdf',
                ), ...
```

And in layout.phtml I do this:

```
...

<div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <!-- Load from module.config.php -->
        <?php 
            echo $this->navigation('navigation')
                ->menu()
                ->setMinDepth(0)
                ->setMaxDepth(0)
                ->setUlClass('nav navbar-nav');
        ?>...
```

On the main page it seems to render ok, but when I navigate to the other module for some reason the module is using its own view helper to render the navbar in layout.phtml and screwing it up. In the module the `$this->navigation('navigation')` part of layout.phtml is fill in with the partial from the module's view helper- yet it still gets the right config from the Application Modules module.config.php. Why is it doing this and how can I prevent the module from using it's view helper to render navbar in layout.phtml?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The nav helpers remember their last state, which includes the menu, the partial used, and min/max depth amongst others.

If you're calling the helper more than once you must reset those values, otherwise they're applied again. In your case, if the partial is the only affected value, use `setPartial()` with a value of `null` to stop the helper from using it again.

```
    <!-- Load from module.config.php -->
    <?php 
        echo $this->navigation('navigation')
            ->menu()
            ->setMinDepth(0)
            ->setMaxDepth(0)
            ->setUlClass('nav navbar-nav')
            ->setPartial(null); // reset partial 
    ?>
```

Comment: Thanks that works. I'm confused though, so it preserve its state because its all in the same navigation container?

Comment: It's the navigation view helpers that preserve state, remembering the last used container, and all the settings you apply to them. It's only a problem when you want to render the same helper more than once in the same request using different parameters, as you're doing here.